# Control Variates, Monte Carlo integration

Tags: self-study, monte-carlo, numerical-integration

Exercise: Calculate $P(N>2.5)$ where $N$~$N(0,1)$ through simple monte carlo integration, and then use control variables to reduce the variance of my estimator.

I did

```
#Simulate Normal Random Variables
 randnormal<- function(n){
        Z<-NULL
        for(i in 1:n){
            U1=runif(1)
            U2=runif(1)
            Z[i]=sqrt(-2*log(U1))*cos(2*U2*pi)
        }
    return(Z)}
```

Then I realized the simple monte carlo integration through

```
#Monte Carlo Integration
montecarlo<-function(n){
    Z=randnormal(n)
    sum(Z>2.5)/n}
```

My question is how can I choose my control variable in this case, there is a criteria for selecting a control variable?

Comment: Something is strange at the outset: your $Z$ will not have a Normal distribution.  This site has a lot of materials about generating Normal variates--please follow the links from a [search](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=generate%20normal%20variate).

Comment: In your previous version,  $Z$ had CDF $\mathbb{P}(Z < z) = e^{zc}/(1 + e^{zc})$  (where $c = 1.702$ or whatever you had).  It reminded me of http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/146772/is-the-first-derivative-of-the-logistic-probability-function-a-gaussian-function :)  Is there some dodgy website somewhere that claims this is Gaussian? :D

Comment: @P.Windridge Yes, I saw it in some reference on the internet which do not remember now.

Comment: Your code could be made clearer by stripping it to its essentials. For instance, `mean(rnorm(1e6)>2.5)` will perform the MC integration very quickly in a single short command, thereby condensing your code to 10% of its original length.

Comment: @whuber The problem is that the discipline of the program requires you generate from the uniform

Comment: Use `qnorm(runif(1e6))` instead of `rnorm(1e6)`, then.  Since your question is not about random number generation, including these details is merely distracting and might confuse readers who otherwise would help you out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The idea behind ["control variates"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_variates) is to use the same Monte-Carlo simulation to estimate the *known* expectation of a function $g$ that is similar to the one, $f$, whose expectation you are trying to estimate.  When $g$ and $f$ are strongly correlated, you can use the errors in estimating $g$ to correct the estimate of $f$.

Therefore **there are two principal criteria** governing your choice of control variate:

1. It must be a function whose expectation you know (or can somehow estimate to a high accuracy).
2. It must be correlated with the target function $f$.

In the present case, $f(z)$ is zero for all $z \lt 2.5$ and jumps to unity for all $z \gt 2.5$.  Any function that will be correlated with it should either tend to increase with increasing $z$ or it should to tend to decrease: that will take care of (2).

Finding a $g$ whose expectation you can easily compute is more of a challenge.  But in writing its formula as

$$\mathbb{E}(g) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_\mathbb{R} g(z) \exp(-z^2/2) dz,$$

ask yourself whether there might be a relatively simple form of $g$ that enables this integral to be calculated.  Indeed there is: one of the simplest choices would be $g(z) = z$, for then the integral could easily be computed using the substitution $z^2/2 = y, z dz = dy$.

Although $g(z)=z$ does work, following criterion (1) we might elect to modify it so that it most closely emulates $f$.  I would suggest doing this by cutting $g$ off so that it's zero when $f$ is zero, whence

$$g(z) = z I(z \ge 2.5)$$

ought to do the trick.  Its expectation is easily found in closed form as

$$\mathbb{E}(g) = \mathbb{E}(z I(z \ge 2.5)) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \exp(-2.5^2/2).$$

You will find that this reduces the estimation variance by a factor of almost $200$--which means that with this technique, you need only $1/200$ as many iterations.  That's a pretty good improvement!

Comment: In an `R` implementation of this solution, using $10^6$ iterations, I can consistently estimate $\Pr(N\gt 2.5)$ to well within $10^{-5}$, while the direct Monte Carlo solution usually errs by about $10^{-4}$.

Comment: I understand everything you did, my last doubts is like is the approach of the estimator $I\approx \sum (f(u_i)+c(g(u_i)-E(g))$ I need to find this $c$